# In an Android app, how can I handle a big xml file as quick as possible? It takes too much time (6 seconds) to be inflated

Tags: android

In an Android application,

I create a `Table Layout` in xml file with 200 rows
Where each row contains **several** *EditTexts, ImageViews,...*

a popup, inflates the mentioned xml file (name:build_m4_configurations_newpage) as following:

```
popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.build_m4_configurations_newpage, null);
```

it takes too much time to be inflated (6 seconds) and I see the following **Error in LogCat**:

> Skipped 144 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its
>   main thread.

How can I handle such a big xml file as quick as possible ?

Comment: If there are 200 rows in your xml, it's better for you to use a `RecyclerView` instead.

Comment: Is it the problem?

Comment: I would say very likely that's the problem. If you use `RecyclerView`, only a few views that are enough to fit the screen are inflated and shown. When you scroll, the views will be updated with your data. That means the system doesn't have to inflate all 200 rows in one shot.

Comment: By the way, I need to create some LinearLayouts in some rows and then add some views there (for example 20 buttons which are horizontally sorted beside each other), is that possible with RecyclerView?

Comment: You can do that with RecyclerView. Looks like you are not familiar with it. It may take some time (a few hours maybe) for you to understand how it works. I suggest you to search for some sample code or tutorial about RecyclerView on Google.

Comment: What if I will have to use a TableLayout? Isn't there a way to go around such a problem?

Comment: As far as I know, Tablelayout doesn't optimize for large number of views.